# Get remote url's last modified date with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the last date that a remote url was updated using javascript. I have currently come up with this:

```
function getlastmod(url)
{
    var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", url);
    ifrm.setAttribute("id", "oIFRAME");
    ifrm.style.display = "none"; 
    var spanTag = document.createElement("span"); 
    spanTag.id = "oSpan"; 
    try 
    {
        var oIFrame = document.getElementById("oIFrame");
        var oSpan = document.getElementById("oSpan");
        oSpan.innerHTML = oIFrame.src + " last modified " +
        oIFrame.document.lastModified;
        outUpdate=oSpan;
    } 
    catch(E) {setTimeout("getlastmod();",50);}
}
```

However, this code seems to always change 'outUpdate' to "undefined". The code is supposed to load the url contents into a frame and then use the document.lastModified function to get the last modified date.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!
Josh

Comment: What variable outUpdate is? is it global or you intend to return it by this function?

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan It is a global variable which is used later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the element `oIFRAME` & `oSpan` before adding them to your document, you have to add these 2 lines before the `try` block:

```
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
document.body.appendChild(spanTag);
```

The id of your `iFrame` is **oIFRAME** and not **oIFrame**, replace this line:

```
var oIFrame = document.getElementById("oIFrame");
```

By

```
var oIFrame = document.getElementById("oIFRAME");
```

`document` is not a property of your `iFrame` object, `contentDocument` is. Replace this line

```
oIFrame.document.lastModified;
```

by

```
oIFrame.contentDocument.lastModified;
```

Comment: Thanks for your very descriptive reply! I have changed the code accordingly but outUpdate now takes on the value of "[object HTMLSpanElement]"
I need it to just get the value of the modified date?

Comment: you have to replace `outUpdate=oSpan` by `outUpdate=oSpan.textContent` OR `outUpdate=oSpan.innerHTML` both works.

Comment: Thanks! However, it appears to be returning the exact current date and time, rather than the date modified?

Comment: The lastModified property returns the date and time the current document was last modified that is equal to the date and time the `src` property of your iframe was changed thats why you are seeing the "exact current date and time".

Comment: So this method is not able to remotely get the lastModified date of a url?

Answer (score 1):

Why is it in try catch statement? Do you expect it to throw any error? Because you basically rely on that. Do you set initial value for outUpdate? Does it ever enters catch statement? 
Why do you have to functions here getlastmod() and getLastModified()?
What happens when you set it to:

```
var outUpdate = "init";
...

...
getlastmod("/");
console.log("outUpdate is: ", outUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not going to display the page you could save yourself some bandwidth by using xhr.
Here's something to get you going...

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Get last modified header with XHR.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Get last modified header with XHR.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style='width : 400px;'>
    <div id="message">Getting File.....</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/lastmodified.htm', true);

xhr.onerror = function() {
    var message = document.querySelector('#message');
    message.innerText = 'Error getting url';
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // readystate 2, headers recieved
    if (this.readyState == 2){
        var message = document.querySelector('#message');
        if (this.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")){
            message.innerText = 'Got the headers\n';
            message.innerText += 'Last Last-Modified : ' + this.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
        } else {
            message.innerText = 'Got the headers\n';
            message.innerText += 'But there was no Last-Modified\n';
            // If the file doesnt exist your still going to get headers
            message.innerText += 'Or there was an error in getting the file';
        }
        // Make sure you access the headers before this abort, as they wont be available afterwards
        this.abort();
    }
}

xhr.send();
```